# How add another class to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

here's my js:

```
function DoNav(theUrl) {
  document.location.href = theUrl;
}
```

here's my alternating color table code

```
while($i < $num) {
  if ($i % 2 == 0) {
    echo "<tr class='even' onclick=\"DoNav('physicianInfo.php');\">";
  }
  else {
    echo "<tr class='odd' onclick=\"DoNav('physicianInfo.php');\">";
  }
}
```

but I wanted to add a `class="colorbox"` when I click the row

class colorbox allows me to have an iframe modal: http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/

since my TR has a class for alternating colors, and I have a clickable row with javascript to open a link `physicianInfo.php`. How can I call colorbox (`class="colorbox"`) inside the tr. can I have 2 class in 1?

I usually call the class via "a href"

Sample: `<a class='colorbox' href="physicianInfo.php">`

Comment: You've asked 18 previous questions. With respect, you should be formatting code correctly by now. We help newbies out by doing it for them, but after a couple of questions, you're expected to handle it yourself. To the right when you were asking your question there was this handy **How to Format** box. Worth a read, as is the information shown by the **[?]** just above the question area and [the page it links to](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: If you need to add a colorbox after rendering the page, you need to look here http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/ and likely do this.colorBox(.....) and not add a class that is not picked up by the plugin unless you re-init the plugin after adding the class

Comment: @mplungjan: I add 'this.colorbox({href:theURL}); but the colorbox effect did not work. Here's the JS:  function DoNav(theUrl)
  {
  document.location.href = theUrl;
  this.colorbox({href:theUrl});
  }

Comment: I have only a vague idea of what you are trying to achieve but I do see you are throwing seemingly random script around. You cannot change the location and have stuff do things on the same page since changing the location unloads the page. You need to change the location of the iframe if you have one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to initialize the plugin properly, since you are adding the html dynamically after page load.

```
while($i < $num) {
    if ($i % 2 == 0) {
        echo "<tr class='even tr-colorbox' \">";
    } else {
        echo "<tr class='odd tr-colorbox' \">";
    }
}

$('.tr-colorbox').colorbox({href: 'physicianInfo.php', iframe: true});
```

Another option

```
function DoNav(theUrl) {
    $.colorbox({href: theUrl, iframe: true});
}

while($i < $num) {
    if ($i % 2 == 0) {
        echo "<tr class='even' onclick=\"DoNav('physicianInfo.php');\">";
    } else {
        echo "<tr class='odd' onclick=\"DoNav('physicianInfo.php');\">";
    }
}
```

Comment: When user click on the row from the table. It opens the link "physicianInfo.php". BUT I want to have the colorbox effect using Example7: http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/core/example1/index.html under "Other Content Types" - Outside Webpage (Iframe) demo

Comment: I tried your code: <script type="text/javascript">
$('.example7').colorbox({href: theUrl});
 </script> and colorbox effect work for like less than a second and the link still opens in the same window now inside the colorbox ifrane

Comment: @Arnold Porche Villaluz I've updated my answer to provide the behavior I believe you are after

Comment: I tried your code: <script type="text/javascript"> $('.tr-colorbox').colorbox({href: 'physicianInfo'}); </script> and colorbox effect work for like less than a second and the link still opens in the same window not inside the colorbox iframe

Comment: IT FINALLY WORK! WOOHOO! I'm referring to the other Option. Thanks Clayton!

Answer (score 0):

```
.addClass('colorbox')
```

would probably be the answer you want :)

Comment: I added this inside javascript: <script type="text/javascript">
  function DoNav(theUrl)
  {
  document.location.href = theUrl;
  .addClass('colorbox');
  }
  </script> it didn't work

Comment: i also tried to add another line inside the javascript:  document.location.addClass('colorbox'); didn't work either

Comment: You need to `this.addClass('colorbox')` in your Javascript.  See if that works

Comment: link works, but colorbox effect do not work. It only works with <a class='colorbox' hred="physicianInfo.php">

Answer (score 0):

Probable solution:

1. in the doNav function get classes for the row
2. then append colorbox class with those.
3. then use javascript setAttribute method

The javascript function should be as follows

```
 function doNav(row,theUrl){
 // document.location.href = theUrl;
 var classes = row.getAttribute("class");
 classes+=" colorbox";
 row.setAttribute("class",classes); 
}
```

The full solution could be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7jmBx/7/). I did this in jsfiddle for you.

But I am afraid that colorbox plugin will not react if you add classname (.colorbox) on the fly. It expect the class on document load.